# URLSession is not getting timeout after specified interval in swift 3 on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to hit a Json request in swift3 through urlsession. Request is not getting timeout after 10s

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:url )! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0 )
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = RequestBody
        let configuration =
            URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self as? URLSessionDelegate, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in...


}
```

Comment: @DávidPásztor Sorry for wrong title. I was using URLSession Only still i am getting the issue

Comment: Bear in mind that the timeout you're setting is the *idle* timeout, which fires only if the request gets no data for more than *n* seconds.  If the app is still getting data slowly, that timer will keep getting reset.  BTW, setting such a short timeout is strongly discouraged.  Cellular networks are often very slow, so unless you're doing something very unusual, you're almost guaranteed to cause serious problems for your users by doing this.  What are you trying to accomplish with such a short timeout?  Having that information might help us recommend better ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you never actually start the network request.
You need to call dataTask.resume() to actually start the request. This needs to happen right after the closure, see code below:

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0 )
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = RequestBody

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in...

}
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: i used data task.resume() in my code I didn't added the syntax on my question still i am not getting timeout